# retrieving a list element in O(1) in R

Tags: r, performance, search, file-io

suppose I have the following:

```
a <- vector('list',50)

for(i in 1:50)
{
  a[[i]] <- list(path=paste0("file",sample(0:600,1)),contents=sample(1:5,10*i,replace=TRUE))
}
```

Now, for example; I want to retrieve the contents of `file45`(assuming it exists in this randomly generated data) as fast as possible.

I have tried the following:

```
contents <- unlist(Filter(function(x) x$path=="file45",a),recursive=FALSE)$contents
```

However, the list searching overhead makes reading from memory even slower than reading directly from disk (to some extent).

Is there any other way of retrieving the contents in something reasonably faster than reading from disk ideally O(1) ?

**edit:** assume that there are no duplicate `filepaths` in my sublists and that there are largely more than 50 sublists

Comment: Are you expecting duplicates in the path variable?

Comment: @James there are no duplicates contrary to what my poorly written example might suggest. Assume that `sample(0:600,1)` wouldn't return any duplicates throughout the 50 iterations i.e no duplicate filepaths

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `names` attribute to track the items instead:

```
a <- vector('list',50)

for(i in 1:50)
{
  a[[i]] <- list(contents=sample(1:5,10*i,replace=TRUE))
}

names(a) <- paste0("file",sample(1:600,50))

a[["file45"]]
NULL
a[["file25"]]
$contents
 [1] 3 1 3 1 2 5 1 5 1 2 3 1 4 1 1 4 1 5 1 5 1 4 5 2 5 2 2 5 1 1
```

Comment: You would have to do it as `names(a)[i] <- ...`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
a[sapply(a, function(x) x$path == "file45")][[1]]$contents
```

Comment: unfortunately, this is still slower than reading from a file. maybe this would be better if I had a really large file. still, I would prefer something close to O(1)